# Differences between regular server and AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If I have a AWS instance, paid normally and not using the on-demand feature.

Are there any differences I should be aware of between this setup and a regular VPS.

I.e. are there things I won't be able to do on this instance, that I can do  on.. say a digitalocean droplet (hosting an web server, email server, nextcloud instance)? or is an EC2 instance just a normal linux server?

Asking because the lowest tier EC2 instance seems to be ~ 2$ per month where the equivalent low tier on digital ocean is 4$ per month, and I want to know if there are any catches to this low price

Comment: A DigitalOcean Droplet, and an EC2 Instance are both Virtual Linux Servers. There's no real difference in what they are, or what the capabilities are.

Comment: While the lowest-spec EC2 instance might be less than the smallest droplet (and btw, I come up with $3.07/month for a t4g.nano), it only includes the virtual machine. You'll also pay for disk storage (EBS), at $0.10/GB/month, and you'll pay for bandwidth, at $0.09/GB (all prices for US zones; other zones may differ). Against that, there's the AWS "free tier," which gives you one year's free usage of a particular spec (but charges you if you go over that, for example excess bandwidth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Paid normally" is normally "on-demand pricing", which simply means you pay for it when it is running and there is no charge when it is stopped.

A virtual computer on Amazon EC2 is effectively the same as a virtual computer on Digital Ocean. You can, of course, select the operating system and software you wish to install.

Normally, Amazon EC2 instances give you a guaranteed amount of Compute CPU, RAM, and Networking. Nobody else can impact your usage of the instance. However, Amazon EC2 has many 'instance types', and some of those types are [Burstable performance instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html). Burstable instances receive a variable amount of compute power and if you try to use 'too much' compute then the CPU will be limited.

This is similar to Digital Ocean. From [Choosing the Right Droplet Plan :: DigitalOcean Documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/concepts/choosing-a-plan/):

> Dedicated CPU Droplets have guaranteed access to the full hyper-thread at all times. With shared CPU Droplets, the hyper-thread allocated to the Droplet may be shared between multiple other Droplets. When a shared CPU Droplet experiences heavier load, the hypervisor dynamically allocates more hyper-thread(s) to it.
>
> However, the amount of CPU cycles available for the hypervisor to allocate depends on the workload of the other Droplets sharing that host. If these neighboring Droplets have high load, a Droplet could receive fractions of hyper-threads instead of dedicated access to the underlying physical processors. In practice, this means that shared CPU Droplets can have access to full hyper-threads, but it’s not guaranteed.

If you merely wish to run a VPS, you might consider using [Amazon Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/), which offers a monthly fixed-price that includes a portion of Data Transfer. This is the closest offering to VPS companies. In some cases, the CPUs of these machines are shared.

**Bottom line:** All computers run the same operating system, so you can do whatever you want on a VPS, an Amazon EC2 instance, a Digital Ocean droplet, a Lightsail instance, etc. They are all just normal computers. However, you will choose a type of instance that determines the amount of CPU and RAM, which will impact the performance of the instance.